# How to duplicate and retrieve data from an UIView with many UITextviews in it

Tags: ios, uiview, clone

I am trying to understand the best approach to create something like this:

[image: UIViews]

I would like to know how to clone the UIViews and retrieving each data from UITextViews above.
I am using storyboard here, is it can be done by adding container view?

Thanks!

Update

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[tableView registerClass: [TitleCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Title"];
TitleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Title" forIndexPath:indexPath];

switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell.leftLabel.text = @"Title";
        //cell.labelRight.text = self.theData[indexPath.section][@"Title"];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.leftLabel.text = @"FirstName";
        //cell.labelRight.text = self.theData[indexPath.section][@"FirstName"];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.leftLabel.text = @"LastName";
        //cell.labelRight.text = self.theData[indexPath.section][@"LastName"];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
   return cell;
}
```

It's not returning error now, but the weird thing is that it didn't show up the leftLabel text.

[image: Table View]

Yes I am using storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to implement that is with a UITableView, you don't need to "clone" anything. The image you posted looks like a table view with sections, with each section having 5 rows. The cells each have two labels, one on the left with fixed text, and one on the right with data which you would populate from a data source. Here's an example that has 3 rows per section. The data source is an array of dictionaries with keys, Title, FirstName, and LastName.

```
self.theData = @[@{@"Title":@"Mr",@"FirstName":@"Joe",@"LastName":@"Montana"},@{@"Title":@"Dr",@"FirstName":@"Julius",@"LastName":@"Irving"},@{@"Title":@"Mr",@"FirstName":@"Alex",@"LastName":@"Smith"}];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.labelLeft.text = @"Title";
            cell.labelRight.text = self.theData[indexPath.section][@"Title"];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.labelLeft.text = @"FirstName";
            cell.labelRight.text = self.theData[indexPath.section][@"FirstName"];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.labelLeft.text = @"LastName";
            cell.labelRight.text = self.theData[indexPath.section][@"LastName"];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Ah now I see that, But is it using dynamic cell or static? if it uses dynamic cell, it means I had to create 5 custom cells?

Comment: @xeravim, I would assume that it's dynamic, if there are many rows. But no, you don't have to create 5 custom cells -- it's just one type of cell with two labels. See my update for an example

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but now I am getting this: "unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Title - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard" why is that?

Comment: @xeravim, where did you make your cell? If in a storyboard, make sure you give it the identifier, "Title".

Comment: I am making it on storyboard. please see my update. it's not one type, but maybe two types, one with 2 labels and the other one is 1 label with 1 UITextField.

Comment: @xeravim, when you make a cell in the storyboard, you shouldn't register the class. If you give the cell an identifier in IB, and use that same identifier in cellForRowAtIndexPath, that's all you should need to do.

Comment: Yeah I made it! Thanks rdelmar!!